# Populate a pie chart dynamicaly with a range bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, d3.js, highcharts

I need to populate a pie chart dynamicaly with a PHP script I have.

My concept have a range bar that updates the series according to the values contained for each index in the json. I found a pie graph that looks like that: http://codepen.io/KenFalcon/pen/OVKOZB.

However I think it is not implemented with json.

I have another example, but this one only accepts 2 values by default (value 1 and value 2). Here it is http://codepen.io/jaybaz1/pen/blgfh

```
  $.getJSON('https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/132755/GetTableData.json', function(data, response){
  var JSONRowData = data.ResponseData[0].RowData;

  $.each(JSONRowData, function(i){
  var $this = $(this);
  //Save each column value into a seperate array
  commonality.arrays.complete_data.push([$this[1], $this[2]]);
  commonality.arrays.commonality.push(parseFloat($this[0]));

  var to = parseInt($this[1]),
  to2 = to.toFixed(2),
  from = parseInt($this[2]),
  from2 = from.toFixed(2);

  commonality.arrays.coverageTo.push(to);
  commonality.arrays.coverageFrom.push(from);

  //Set default array values
  commonality.value.commonality = commonality.arrays.commonality[0];
  commonality.value.coverageTo = commonality.arrays.coverageTo[0];
  commonality.value.coverageFrom = commonality.arrays.coverageFrom[0];
  });

  var a = new RBM_init_commonality.pieChart(commonality.arrays.div[0]);
  var b = new RBM_init_commonality.pieChart(commonality.arrays.div[1]);

  update_graph(a, b);
  slider(a, b);
});
```

This sample is good because it uses a json similar to mine. 
In this example, for each row in the Json skiping the index it would plot another slice with the respective value.

Then for a bar ranging from 1 to 10, The json would be something like this:

[ [ 1, 48, 52 ], 
[ 2, 49, 51 ],
... 
[ 10, 57, 43 ] ]

So this:

[ [ 1, 33, 33, 34 ], 
[ 2, 32,5, 32,5, 35 ],
... 
[ 10, 28,5, 28,5, 43 ] ]

Should generate a 3 slice graph.

Tried all the samples from Highcharts, amcharts and others but couldn't find the solution.
PS: I'm new to javascript.

Any idea?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I use google charts, easy to use and flexible with data. You can definitely use json and the example [here](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/controls) sounds like what you want...

Comment: In this case I would use an input with only one selector ranging from 1 to 10 parsing the first row values. Is it possible with google charts?

Comment: definitely possible, the trick is in using [`arrayToDataTable`](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#arraytodatatable) to build the array you need but I don't follow the question exactly...

Comment: Reffering to highcharts, see the artice about working with data: http://www.highcharts.com/docs/working-with-data/custom-preprocessing